# Laundry standpipe overflow when separate sink pump runs at same time only

Tags: pump, laundry

My Laundry standpipe and a separate sink pump are connected to the same branch drain drain line.  My laundry room is in the basement.  I can do laundry no problem by itself, but if the sink is used (and sink pump runs) at the same time as doing laundry the laundry standpipe overflows.

This has always happened but looking to finally fix it now.

My plumbing is as follows (all using 2" PVC, except for main drain line connecting to sewer):

Main House Drain Line <-------Branch Drain (3 feet) <-------"T"  connects to Sink Pump and separately to Laundry Stand Pipe Trap with a Check Valve in between Sink Pump and Trap.

I was thinking that I could add an Air Admittance Valve to the Stand-Pipe, but not sure if that will help.  I am guessing the pressure from the Sink Pump will not allow the standpipe water to flow through the check valve.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

There are pictures and diagrams located here:

https://www.ridgidforum.com/forum/mechanical-trades/ask-the-plumbing-experts/743879-laundry-stand-pipe-oveflow-when-sink-pump-and-washing-machine-runs-at-same-time

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture and/or diagram of the drain piping? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could draw a layout of what you are proposing to do. Pictures also help us to help you.

Comment: Seems like the problem is that the BranchDrain (after the "T") is either dirty or of insufficient diameter to handle the combined flow rate.  Check valves will not help this.

Comment: Upon viewing your diagram,  my comment stands: it's the pipe between the two standpipes and the main waste line that can't handle the total volume.  If the check-valve cuts in, then the laundry outflow will back up anyway

Comment: Would increasing the pipe size between the the check valve and the main drain line resolve this or is their a easier more effective way to solve this?  Possibly also connecting the sink basin pump directly to the main drain line.  What do you recommend?